# looking for groovy log4j2 rollingfileappender example

Tags: groovy, log4j2

Looking for Groovy help in configuring log4j2 RollingFileAppenders.

I have this simple example working but of course it "logs" to stdout.

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j2

@Log4j2
class MyApp {
  static void main(String[] args) {
    log.error "Hello world!"
  }
}
```

```bash
$ export CLASSPATH=$LIBS/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar:$LIBS/log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
$ groovy my-example.groovy
13:44:16.939 [main] ERROR MyApp - Hello world!
```

I am looking for some Groovy-oriented examples of how to configure a RollingFileAppender so I could log to files (and have them auto-rotate, control the format, etc).

There are lots of Java examples available but I am hoping to find something more Groovy-like.    :)

EDIT - here's an example of some Java configuration I was hoping to avoid -

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.AppenderComponentBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ComponentBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.ConfigurationBuilderFactory
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.FilterComponentBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.LayoutComponentBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.LoggerComponentBuilder
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.api.RootLoggerComponentBuilder


// configure console appender
ConfigurationBuilder builder
    = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder()

AppenderComponentBuilder console
    = builder.newAppender("stdout", "Console")

builder.add(console)

// configure log file
AppenderComponentBuilder file
    = builder.newAppender("log", "File")

file.addAttribute("fileName", "myapp.log")

builder.add(file)

// configure rolling file appender
AppenderComponentBuilder rollingFile
    = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")

rollingFile.addAttribute("fileName", "myapp.log")

rollingFile.addAttribute("filePattern", "myapp-%d{MM-dd-yy}.log.gz")

builder.add(rollingFile)

// configure filters
FilterComponentBuilder flow = builder.newFilter(
    "MarkerFilter",
    Filter.Result.ACCEPT,
    Filter.Result.DENY)

flow.addAttribute("marker", "FLOW")

console.add(flow)

// configure log record format
LayoutComponentBuilder standard
    = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")

standard.addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable")

console.add(standard)

file.add(standard)

rollingFile.add(standard)

// configure rootLogger
RootLoggerComponentBuilder rootLogger
    = builder.newRootLogger(Level.ERROR)

rootLogger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("stdout"))

builder.add(rootLogger)

// configuring additional loggers
LoggerComponentBuilder logger = builder.newLogger("com", Level.DEBUG)

logger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("log"))

logger.addAttribute("additivity", false)

builder.add(logger);

// configuring other components, e.g. triggering policy for rolling file appenders
ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicies = builder.newComponent("Policies")
    .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy")
        .addAttribute("schedule", "0 0 0 * * ?"))
    .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy")
        .addAttribute("size", "100M"))

rollingFile.addComponent(triggeringPolicies)

// initialize logger
Configurator.initialize(builder.build())
```

Now granted, not all of that configuration is required but there's a lot of what some might call "boilerplate".   :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Isn't this just some config, thats the same for java and groovy? Or why is your java version not groovy enough? Please add the config you are not happy with or what you have tried to make it more groovy and failed (e.g. code, stacktraces, ...)

Comment: @cfrick - I added some sample log4j2 config to the example...  i see the need/functionality of it but I was expecting something much more streamlined in groovy.  Is this pretty much how it's done?  I read through the info at https://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_logging_improvements and it looks like what I'm looking for but it doesn't cover anything about appenders or how to configure them.